# Why is HTML stored in a variable not displaying as HTML?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created my layout in application.html.erb.

I want to include a few dynamic fields provided from the view. In application.html.erb file I have:

```
  <p style="margin-left: 45px">
     <%= yield ( :article_heading ) %>
  </p>
```

Then in static_page/home.html.erb I have:

```
<% provide(:article_heading, 'Contact N&ugrave;R&ugrave;mie') %>
```

The HTML is not being properly parsed. Instead of producing the accent marks, it returns the string exactly.

Comment: Try appending an `.html_safe` to the end of the string: `'Contact N&ugrave;R&ugrave;mie'.html_safe`. See also: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/

Comment: That worked I never thought of of using the html_safe method first, If you want post it as the answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = "this is some <p>html content</p>"
```

if in your view you do

```
  <%= x %>
```

then you'll get exactly that string, but this will be interpreted as html code if you do

```
  <%= x.html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny this did work but the answer in the comment by Shioyama was actually the best method and fit my current usage.

Comment: You are welcome, glad i can help but as i see Shioyama and I wrote exactly the same thing simultaneously, that variable can be a string too.

Comment: Yep thanks I chose you answer since I am not sure where Shioyama is